# Capture times from a string

Tags: regex, perl

I want to capture hours from file txt.  For example:

In file there is some article. I'd like to take hours:

```
11:51
00:32
```

but I can't take `13:51` or `11:61`.  My current code doesn't work.

```
while ($word = <$fh>) {
    if ($word =~ /\d\d:\d\d/) {
        print $word . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't treat regexes like a crutch.  If you do that, you fall into [`XY Problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) land.

If you can validate your captures using a simple `if` statement, then do so.  Don't get hung up on one solution method:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    while ($line =~ /\b(\d\d:\d\d)\b/g) {
        my $time = $1;
        my ($hour, $min) = split ':', $time;
        if ($hour < 13 && $min < 60) {
            print "Time = $time\n"
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
11:51
00:32
13:51
11:61
```

Outputs:

```
Time = 11:51
Time = 00:32
```

Comment: ok, but what if file contains in one line two or more hours, for example:
10:51 dsadabjkd  sad dsadas 10:27 04:21
?

Comment: Then instead of `if ($line =~ /\b(\d\d:\d\d)\b/) {` use a `while ($line =~ /\b(\d\d:\d\d)\b/g) {`  *Updated the code.*

Comment: ok :)
Now, What if I would like replace the hour in file with for example XX:XX HOUR
Example: 11:51  -> 11:51 HOUR

Comment: Your new spec isn't clear.   If you're wanting to replace things instead of matching, then you're going to need to use `s///` in some way instead of `m//`.  However, SO isn't really for hand holding through a roving specification.  If you have another problem, then feel free to post a new question after you've tried to solve it on your own of course.  But any further changes to this answer would not be addressing the question as listed above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time in AM/PM format and can't have above 12:00, then you need to use numeric ranges:

```
/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]\d/
```

`(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])` will match either `0[1-9]` (01-09) or `1[0-2]` (10-12).

`[0-5]\d` will match 00-59.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh, woops, haha, I don't know how I got that one xD Thanks!

Comment: Note that I didn't say nothing about 12 the hour of the crime.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that's what I get for never using the AM/PM format... Just checked wikipedia and found that 00:00 is not valid -_-.

Comment: Glups, when I think about all these digital clocks that display 00:00 instead of 12:00

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match hour, but only in lines that look like your sample.

```
^\d\d?(?=:\d\d?$)
```

Remove the question marks if hour and minute are always 2 digits.

Comment: I think he wants to ensure that hours are not greater than 11 and minutes than 59

Comment: I don't know, but these are my goto regex sites
http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course the perl documentation [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) is the standard reference, but for reading along and trying things, you might look at [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aDebugger) which installs a great command line regular expression editor and analysis tool called `rxrx`. It's very simple but can be quite helpful in getting a feel for how the regular expression engine works.

If you're open to installing CPAN modules you'll get lots of help from the `Regexp::Common` namespace (in your case [`Regexp::Common::time`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3atime) might be useful).  The `Regexp::Common:: ...` modules simplify and "standardize" regular expressions for common categories. The best part is you can read the source code to figure out how to do it yourself if you are in a situation where CPAN modules are unavailable.

Here's @Miller' example using `Regexp::Common::time`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl5 
use strict;       
use warnings; 
use Regexp::Common qw(time);

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  if ($line =~ $RE{time}{hms}{-keep}) { 
    print "Time = $2:$3 \n";  
  } 
}    

__DATA__         
11:51          
00:32  
13:51                                                                           
11:61
```

Note that this will print **`3`** values as is, (here in Canada `13:51` is almost coffee time). See the POD for how to limit time patterns using `strftime` compatible formats.  It's also possible to use the module and fiddle with output in normal `perl` manner (e.g.`print "Time = $2:$3 \n" unless $2 > 12;`).

@Miller's approach is the simplest (+1 from me), but `Regexp::Common` is a very useful tool.

Cheers,